# Storing data with big and dynamic groupings / paths

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I currently have the following pig script (column list truncated for brevity):

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;

inputData = LOAD '/data/$date*.{bz2,bz,gz}' USING PigStorage('\\x7F')
PigStorage('\\x7F')
AS (
SITE_ID_COL                 :int,--                     = Item Site ID
META_ID_COL                 :int,--                 = Top Level (meta) category ID
EXTRACT_DATE_COL            :chararray,--          = Date for the data points
...
)

SPLIT inputData INTO site0 IF (SITE_ID_COL == 0), site3 IF (SITE_ID_COL == 3), site15 IF (SITE_ID_COL == 15);

STORE site0 INTO 'pigsplit1/0/' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('pigsplit1/0/','2', 'bz2', '\\x7F');
STORE site3 INTO 'pigsplit1/3/' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('pigsplit1/3/','2', 'bz2', '\\x7F');
STORE site15 INTO 'pigsplit1/15/' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('pigsplit1/15/','2', 'bz2', '\\x7F');
```

And it works great for what I wanted it to do, but there's actually at least 22 possible site IDs and I'm not certain there's not more. I'd like to dynamically create the splits and store into paths based on that column. Is the easiest way to do this going to be through a two step usage of the MultiStorage UDF, first splitting by the site ID and then loading all those results and splitting by the date? That seems inefficient. Can I somehow do it through GROUP BYs? It seems like I should be able to GROUP BY the site ID, then flatten each row and run the multi storage on that, but I'm not sure how to concatenate the GROUP into the path.

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiStorage` UDF is not set up to divide inputs on two different fields, but that's essentially what you're doing -- the use of `SPLIT` is just to emulate `MultiStorage` with two parameters. In that case, I'd recommend the following:

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;

inputData = LOAD '/data/$date*.{bz2,bz,gz}' USING PigStorage('\\x7F')
AS (
SITE_ID_COL                 :int,--                     = Item Site ID
META_ID_COL                 :int,--                 = Top Level (meta) category ID
EXTRACT_DATE_COL            :chararray,--          = Date for the data points
...
)

dataWithKey = FOREACH inputData GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT(SITE_ID_COL, '-'), EXTRACT_DATE_COL), *;

STORE dataWithKey INTO 'tmpDir' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('tmpDir', '0', 'bz2', '\\x7F');
```

Then go over your output with a simple script to list all the files in your output directories, extract the site and date IDs, and move them to appropriate locations with whatever structure you like.

Not the most elegant workaround, but it could work all right for you. One thing to watch out for is the separator you choose in your key might not be allowed (it might only be alphanumeric).  Also, you'll be stuck with that extra field in your output data.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually submitted a patch to the MultiStorage module to allow splitting on multiple tuple fields rather than only one, resulting in a dynamic output tree.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3258

It hasn't gotten much attention yet, but I'm using it in production with no issues.